How can use Custom SQL with parameters in Looker Studio?
I trying to using Custom SQL with parameters in Looker studio (like this other question
How to find users who logged in every single day to the app?), but this options is not available for me. Why?
enter image description here
I tried to use custom parameter in SQL custom query
